# Strange String.split(“\n”) behavior

Tags: java, regex

I tried to split `name` but none of the tries using split method worked

```
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
   String name="PU_Y"+
               "PU-x"+
               "Pu-z";

    split = name.split("\\r\\n");
    split = name.split("\r\n");
    split = name.split("[\r\n]+");
    split = name.split("[\\r\\n]+");
    split = name.split("\\r?\\n");
    // I tried using all the above to split above string but was not successful
}
```

Please help to split this string

Comment: There's no EOL symbols in the result of string concatenation, as no part of it contains EOL symbol (and whitespace separating operands and `+` symbol is ignored).

Comment: Also note that your title (which matches LF) doesn't match your question body (which matches CRLF)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your string doesn't contain any line breaks at all. The fact that you've concatenated it on multiple lines doesn't do anything. Your statement is equivalent to:

```
String name = "PU_Y" + "PU-x" + "Pu-z";
```

or

```
String name = "PU_YPU-xPu-z";
```

You probably meant:

```
String name = "PU_Y\r\n" +
              "PU-x\r\n" +
              "Pu-z";
```

Retest your regular expressions with that change.

Answer (score 5):

Your string has no linebreaks in it, every time you start a new line, you are concatenating strings as one statement.

Your string will be:

```
"PU_YPU-xPu-z"
```

If you want newlines, put a `\r\n` in the String before you terminate the string on each line:

```
String name="PU_Y\r\n"+
            "PU-x\r\n"+
            "Pu-z\r\n";
```